# Caching the data and querying it

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, caching

I have a requirement where I need to cache the database table which has 3 columns (ID,STRING,STRING) and query it on the basis of id in C#. I searched a lot of articles on Stack Overflow but couldn't figure out the one which solve this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Create Entity Class: You can create a class with these three fields

Create Cache Class: This class will have a collection of Entity class (repository) and store it in session on first request, for all subsequent request check if the repository has values then return from the repository else load the repository from database and return.

Let me know if you need sample structure.

```
private class MyEntity
{
  public int ID {get;set;}
  public String String1 {get;set;}
  public String String2 {get;set;}
}

public class Repository
{
    List<MyEntity> myEntityCollection{get;set;}
    List<MyEntity> MyEntityCollection
    {
        get
        {
            if (myEntityCollection == null) { LoadAndFillMyEntityCollectionFromDatabase(); } 
            return myEntityCollection;
        }
    }

    public MyEntity GetMyEntity(int id)
    {
        return MyEntityCollection.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ID == id);
    }
}
```

here is a sample class structure, where LoadAndFillMyEntityCollectionFromDatabase is a method which loads myEntityCollection collection from database.

I've written it right here , you might need to do some small changes if it is not compiling.

Comment: Thanks Imran, it would be great if you can send a sample structure

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use `Lucene` indexing engine to cache and query the data. Have a look: [Lucene .NET Wrapper Reference](http://lucenenet.apache.org/)

**[edit]**

It's really easy to use this and works really quickly:) Tested and approved:) Btw. some ppl use `SQLite` to cache the data and query them (fast and uses local drive to store the data)